How can i delete default title tag from wordpress?
I used this code

remove_action('wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1);

to remove default title tag from WordPress. This helped the WordPress theme till Twenty Twenty One. But from Twently Twenty Two. This code didn't remove the title tag.
How can I remove the default title tag? Is there any alternative? Is there any resources on how WordPress or FSE Themes handles default title tags.

You can use this method for functions.php
function custom_remove_title_tag() {
    ob_start(function($buffer) {
        return preg_replace('/<title>.*<\/title>/i', '', $buffer);
    });
}
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_remove_title_tag', 0);


But I recomend to use some plugin for rewrite <title>
